# Timezone with Postgres on Windows

Tags: database, postgresql, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am storing a time field in a `timestamp without timezone` column.  The data is stored in UTC time.  When I call the data back on heroku I get somehting like `2013-07-13T18:06:41.000Z` which is what I want.

However, on my test machine, which is running windows 8 and postgres 9.3 I get this back `Sat Jul 13 2013 18:06:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`. This is the right time sort of.  It is the correct time with the offset to local time.

How can I match my production db to return the same or similar results to my test db?

Comment: Could you please show some code where you are fetching the data?  Clearly the timestamp is being interpreted in the local timezone of the server, and not as UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run your test server with `TimeZone` set to `UTC`.

You can set this globally in `postgresql.conf`, or on a per-user, per-database, per-session or per-transaction basis.

See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I tried this.  I found more info about the issue and found that it was an error in the node-postgres lib.  The work around seems to be to set the clock on windows to UTC and prevent the conversion to local time.

Comment: @Alexis  Feel free to post that, with appropriate details and links, as an answer to your own question. I'll upvote if you comment here.